# Consume results from function lazily in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a function in my database that returns a lot of rows:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION lots_of_rows(n integer) RETURNS SETOF integer
STABLE LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$ BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..10000000 LOOP
    RETURN NEXT i * n;
  END LOOP;
END $$;
```

Unsurprisingly, queries that use this function are not very fast:

```
=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT n FROM lots_of_rows(4) as n;
                                                          QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Function Scan on lots_of_rows n  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=1867.135..2900.167 rows=10000000 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.026 ms
 Execution Time: 3494.365 ms
(3 rows)
```

That is to be expected. But what frustrates me is that I pay for the whole cost of this function even if I only use a tiny subset of the resulting rows:

```
=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT n FROM lots_of_rows(4) as n LIMIT 10;
                                                          QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.25..0.35 rows=10 width=4) (actual time=1863.679..1863.682 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Function Scan on lots_of_rows n  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=1863.675..1863.676 rows=10 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.044 ms
 Execution Time: 1872.395 ms
(4 rows)
```

Clearly, that is very wasteful. For comparison, if I do the same thing with a recursive view, it takes essentially zero time:

```sql
CREATE RECURSIVE VIEW lots_of_rows (n) AS
    VALUES (1)
  UNION ALL
    SELECT n+1 FROM lots_of_rows WHERE n < 10000000;
```

```
=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT n * 4 FROM lots_of_rows LIMIT 10;
                                                                     QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=2.95..3.28 rows=10 width=4) (actual time=0.005..0.027 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Subquery Scan on lots_of_rows  (cost=2.95..3.96 rows=31 width=4) (actual time=0.005..0.023 rows=10 loops=1)
         ->  CTE Scan on lots_of_rows lots_of_rows_1  (cost=2.95..3.57 rows=31 width=4) (actual time=0.003..0.020 rows=10 loops=1)
               CTE lots_of_rows
                 ->  Recursive Union  (cost=0.00..2.95 rows=31 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.015 rows=10 loops=1)
                       ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)
                       ->  WorkTable Scan on lots_of_rows lots_of_rows_2  (cost=0.00..0.23 rows=3 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=9)
                             Filter: (n < 10000000)
 Planning Time: 0.213 ms
 Execution Time: 0.089 ms
(10 rows)
```

But of course, my function takes an argument, `n`, but views cannot accept arguments, so some of the implementation details have to leak out into my individual queries.

Of course, this `lots_of_rows` function is very silly, and I do not actually literally use it anywhere. My real function is more complex: it accepts several different arguments and uses them to construct a `SELECT` query, iterates over the results using `FOR`, and for certain rows, returns records using `RETURN NEXT`. It is not nearly as simple to replace that particular function with a view.

Furthermore, it is not straightforward to move the limiting logic from my enclosing query into the function, since the enclosing queries sometimes add various `WHERE` conditions to the result:

```sql
SELECT r.id FROM complicated_function($1, $2, $3, $4) as r
WHERE r.is_public AND r.score > 0 LIMIT 20;
```

I guess I could always just add a ton of different arguments to the function for all the different conditions I need, but ideally, I’d *like* to be able to keep my function as it is (since it encapsulates precisely the abstraction I want), just somehow stream the results to the caller on-demand so that it acts a little bit more like a view (albeit still more or less opaque to the query planner). Is that at all possible, or *must* a function’s result be completely materialized in memory before it returns?

Comment: I think you are stuck with it like this...I'd suggest rewriting the function not to have a for loop, but your reputation suggests you've explored that already.  You might be able to break the function into a series of functions...call your main function with alot of parameters and have that function call smaller ones based on parameters.  I don't think there is a graceful answer here

Comment: @Twelfth When you say “rewrite the function to not have a for loop,” what alternative do you have in mind? Writing a function that operates on a single row at a time? Unfortunately, a bulk of the logic is in the query itself, so moving that out of the function would lose most of the function’s value. Originally I was hopeful that using `RETURN QUERY` instead of using `FOR` combined with `RETURN NEXT` would cause Postgres to do something smarter, but alas, it does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Avoid RBAR https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/

Comment: @MichaelBuen Believe me, I agree! I would *much* rather be doing this with a view than a function, and normally I do. I hate that the query planner hasn’t the foggiest idea what my function is doing. But I’ve tried shoving the arguments into view columns I can instead filter on, and I’ve found that the query planner just hates it. If anything, what I’m *really* asking for is some kind of parameterized view, but I am pretty certain Postgres supports nothing of the sort. So I’m trying to find the next best thing without having to copy and paste the same query several different times.

Comment: Make the function deterministic by making the function `IMMUTABLE`, and use `LANGUAGE SQL` instead of 'LANGUAGE PLPGSQL'. It will force you (to rewrite) to write your function in such a way that Postgres won't allow you to use e.g., `FOR, IF` and similar control structures that prevents the RDBMS from seeing the best execution plan for your query. Making your function use `LANGUAGE SQL` and `RETURN QUERY` is a good approach as it forces you to write your function that behaves like a view (with the added flexibility of parameters). I think your  `RETURN QUERY` is just missing `IMMUTABLE`.

Comment: http://bonesmoses.org/2015/05/08/pg-phriday-functions-and-performance-attributes/

Comment: @MichaelBuen My actual functions are `STABLE`, not `IMMUTABLE`, but it seems like you’re right: writing my function in `LANGUAGE SQL` and declaring it `STABLE` seems to be enough for query planner to see through the function! If you write that as an answer, I’d be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be able to achieve what you're looking for by having the function return a [cursor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/plpgsql-cursors.html).

A *cursor* should allow the function caller to fetch rows in batches rather than all at once, allowing both for results to the caller more quickly and less in memory at once on both the client and the server.

**Note:** There is overhead on the server in terms of maintaining the cursor. The caller should close the *cursor* explicitly once done (otherwise it will close at the end of the transaction).

In particular, check out the section in the above link entitled **43.7.3.5. Returning Cursors**.

Comment: I did look into cursors, which I probably should have mentioned in my question. The problem is that there does not appear to be any way to consume a cursor in a subquery, so I cannot have a function return a cursor, then perform a `SELECT` on the result set. If I overlooked something, by all means, let me know what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres has two possible implementation of table functions:

- row based with persistent context - it returns only rows that are required - it is little bit more CPU expensive, but it stop early - with this implementation the function is called multiple times and returns only one row every time. For this implementation only C language can be used.
- tuple store implementation - this is your case - PLpgSQL and other than C language use it. When the function is called, then special structure `tuplestore` is filled. All rows are generated - and all rows are returned. The reader of tuplestore (parent node), can read all rows (or not), but every time all rows are produced. Outer `LIMIT` clause is not push down inside function, so it has not any effect on speed.

There are not any other implementation - so if you need limit result, then you have to do explicitly (manually) (if you want higher programming language).